# Updating to latest nano text editor

Tags: debian, nano

Currently using Debian 8 and preinstalled is nano 2.2.6, I wish to update nano to the latest version which is 2.7.1.

I tried `apt-get remove nano` and installing again using `apt-get install nano`, but it is still version 2.2.6.

Comment: try running `apt-get update` before installing again, maybe you have an old version cached somewhere. Instead of uninstalling and reinstalling, first run `apt-get update` and then run `apt-get upgrade nano`

Comment: I followed and got nano is already the newest version also checked `nano -V` still 2.2.6

Comment: Perhaps nano wasn't updated yet in your repositories. The most recent version for Raspbian using default repos is 2.2.6, Ubuntu 16.04 seems to use 2.5.3, and CloudLinux 6.3 seems to still be at 2.0.9.

Comment: Note that nano for Termux is version 5.8; not sure why the regular nano distribution is several versions lower!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround on this by modifying `/etc/apt/sources.list`

from

```
deb http://mirror.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://mirror.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
```

to

```
deb http://mirror.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://mirror.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
```

Removed `nano` 2.2.6 by `apt-get remove nano` then `apt-get update`

Finally install `nano` by `apt-get install nano`

Check version by `nano -V`

I'm running `nano` version 2.7.0 now

I was logged in as root while doing this so I needed to `cp /bin/nano` to `/usr/bin/nano` so I could launch `nano` directly.

**Note:** Do not forget to revert your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Include as Bryan Cerrati pointed out:

Installation using .deb files.

```
dpkg -i nano_2.7.1.deb
```

Get nano at Debian GNU/Linux binaries [stable](https://packages.debian.org/stable/editors/nano) | [testing](https://packages.debian.org/testing/editors/nano) | [unstable](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/editors/nano)

**Note:** Make sure you properly select the appropriate architecture for your machine.

Answer (score 2):

Nano v.2.7.1 is in Debian `sid` and considered unstable. is not included in wheezy repos by default. you can build it from source or install the .deb package avaliable from debian's mirrors.

Installing .deb file. Depending on your architecture (64 bit or 32 bit) you can download the following packages

- [AMD 64 Machines](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/nano/download)
- [I386 Machines](https://packages.debian.org/sid/i386/nano/download)

heres a Full List of Avaliable Architectures Available [Here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/nano)

Once you have your .deb file, you can install from there.

---

Installation:

```
dpkg -i nano_2.7.1-1_amd64.deb
```

please take a look at the 2.7 release [FAQ](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.7/faq.html). 
If you need advanced installation parameters then compiling from source is contained in the FAQ.

---

NOTE: i did not include the actual downloadable files as im not sure if that is a rule on stack exchange but i pointed you to the correct download pages so the origin is transparent to all viewing this answer

Comment: Note: When I installed this way on Ubuntu, it wrecked the stable install with a non-working version as 3.2.2 had requirements that could not be satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this to be the easiest and quickest way when I setup a VM, tested on fresh Ubuntu 16.04 Server VM:

Edit apt sources list with:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following lines at the bottom:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian unstable main
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian unstable main
```

Save & exit [ctrl-x, y, RETURN]

Update apt package lists, ignore "is not signed" warnings

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If you want to see what versions are available:

```
apt-cache madison nano
```

Remove old version of nano:

```
sudo apt-get -y remove nano
```

Install latest from unstable:

```
sudo apt-get -y --allow-unauthenticated install nano
```

Comment out `unstable` repos from sources list by adding '#' in front of the lines we added in the second step using the new version of nano:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Refresh the package list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Bonus tip - then I create a `.nanorc` file:

```
nano ~/.nanorc
```

With the contents:

```
set quiet
set autoindent
set constantshow
set positionlog
set tabsize 4
set tabstospaces
set nowrap
set suspend
set titlecolor brightyellow,blue
set statuscolor brightyellow,blue
bind ^S savefile main
bind ^G findnext main
bind M-G findprevious main
set backupdir $HOME/nano-backups
set numbercolor cyan,black
set linenumbers
set keycolor cyan,black
set functioncolor blue,black
```